# T-SQL SUM() with row level computation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are implementing currency convention. Some of our clients operate in many countries and some of the orders are placed in the base currency of the company and will not need conversion and some are placed in other countries and will need conversion. We have a currency_rate in the orders table and if the rate is NULL then no conversion is needed and if a rate is there we multiply the order total by the rate for the conversion. My question is - I do not think INSULL() will do the trick.

```
SELECT Sum(ISNULL(order_total,0) * ISNULL(currency_rate,1)) AS [Total] 
FROM   orders
```

The order_total is always stored in the db as the base currency of the company and only converted when needed for display purposes. Some engineers here are worried that this may work on the aggregate and not the row level.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work on a row level?

Comment: `ISNULL()` is fine.  I prefer `COALESCE()` but that is another matter.  The logic should do what you want it to do.

Comment: I would store the currency **type** in the orders table and join to a currency conversion table for display purposes.

Comment: The conversion rate gets stored right in the order table at the time the order is placed - no need to connect with any other tables to do this. This is necessary as rates change over time and the rate that was in effect at the time of the order is what is needed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `ISNULL(order_total,0)` isn't necessary.  `SUM()` ignores null values, and `NULL` multiplied by any value is `NULL`.

Comment: Actually - the DBA is in agreement with @Gordon Linoff - Gordon - if you want to enter your comment as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

But it works on both levels

This is applied at the row level:

```
ISNULL(order_total,0) * ISNULL(currency_rate,1)
```

Sum is just an aggregate of what happened at the row level

To prove the row level run the following:

```
SELECT (ISNULL(order_total,0) * ISNULL(currency_rate,1)) AS [RowTotal] 
FROM   orders
```